# Why I can't get msgbox to show up in a while loop?

Tags: autohotkey

```
MButton::
Send {LWIN down}{TAB down}{LWIN up}{TAB up}
while GetKeyState("MButton")
{
Msgbox 1
}
return
```

I am new to Ahk, hope someone could enlighten me of my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ["p" parameter](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm) to get the actual **p**hysical state of the button:

```js
GetKeyState("MButton","p")
```